# AngularJs object Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, sorting

I have JSON like this inside the main Array Object

```
obj = [{{"title":"1-Introduction"},
       {"title":"5-Introduction"},
       {"title":"20-Introduction"},
       {"title":"4-Introduction"} }]
```

I want to sort the above object like

```
obj = [{{"title":"1-Introduction"},
       {"title":"4-Introduction"},
       {"title":"5-Introduction"},
       {"title":"20-Introduction"} }]
```

what I have tried so far

```
$scope.checkWeightage=function(){
            thisObj.scheduleSubject.map(itm=>itm.sectionRange.map(subItm=>{
                    var min = subItm.chapterActualWeightage-(subItm.chapterActualWeightage/10);
                    var max = subItm.chapterActualWeightage+(subItm.chapterActualWeightage/10);
                    var sum = subItm.items.reduce((total,it)=>{
                       return total+it.actualWeightage;
                    },0);
                    subItm['weightageError'] = (sum>max || sum<min)?true:false;
                    subItm['ChapterActualWeightageCurrently'] = parseFloat(Math.round(sum*100)/100);
                    subItm.items.sort((a,b)=>a.title.split(/_(.+)/)[0]>b.title.split(/_(.+)/)[0]);
                })
            ); console.log(thisObj.scheduleSubject[0].chapterData); //.1[0].title);
            //console.log("CHECK weightage",thisObj.scheduleSubject);
        }
```

How to track title on my main Array

```
alert(thisObj.scheduleSubject[0].sectionRange[0].items[0].title);
```

I want to sort all the items on the base of its title digits before - character example 1- , 2- ,3- ,4-, 5-, 6-, 21-,56- and so on.

Main Array Structure

```
[
  {
    "id": "25",
    "section": "1",
    "sectionRange": [
      {
        "sectionNumber": 1,
        "effectAllowed": "all",
        "Date": "",
        "items": [
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 283,
            "actualWeightage": 3.42,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "10-Creation & Registration of Charges",
            "$$hashKey": "object:146"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 284,
            "actualWeightage": 2.23,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "11-Allotment of Securities & Issue of Certificates",
            "$$hashKey": "object:147"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 285,
            "actualWeightage": 1.37,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "12-Membership in a Company",
            "$$hashKey": "object:148"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 286,
            "actualWeightage": 3.42,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "13-Transfer & Transmission of Securities",
            "$$hashKey": "object:149"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 287,
            "actualWeightage": 7.53,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "14-Institution of Directors",
            "$$hashKey": "object:150"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 288,
            "actualWeightage": 1.37,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "15-Independent Directors",
            "$$hashKey": "object:151"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 289,
            "actualWeightage": 13.35,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "16-Board & its Powers",
            "$$hashKey": "object:152"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 290,
            "actualWeightage": 8.22,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "17-Appointment & Remuneration of Key Managerial Personnel",
            "$$hashKey": "object:153"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 291,
            "actualWeightage": 6.68,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "18-General Meetings",
            "$$hashKey": "object:154"
          },
          {
            "subjectId": 25,
            "section": 1,
            "chapterId": 292,
            "actualWeightage": 1.37,
            "totalPaperMarks": 132,
            "title": "19-Loans & Investments by Companies",
            "$$hashKey": "object:155"
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` on that char and sort via that (assuming your main data structure is named `structure`:

```
structure.forEach(s => {
    s.sectionRange.forEach(sr => {
        sr.items.sort(function(a, b) {
            let aParts = a.split("-"),
                bParts = b.split("-");

            return +aParts[0] - +bParts[0];
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Just extract those number values and let orderBy filter of angularjs do the job for you

**JS**

```
  $scope.getNumber = function(row){
    var value = row.title.split("-")[0];
    return parseInt(value);
  };
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:getNumber:false">{{item.title}}</div>
```

also orderBy takes a second parameter (true / false) for asc / desc ordering

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TFvMDcQRXGVQM5Rlc4bE?p=preview)**

Comment: for simplicity purposes I only included items part of your object in demo

Comment: the above answered solved my problem but I also tried your method and I am getting an error.

 Token 'orderBy' is an unexpected token at column 17 of the expression [container.items orderBy:getNumber(item):true] starting at [orderBy:getNumber(item):true].

Comment: most probably you copied something wrong, please compare your code with the example provided in plnkr demo. Also if you can create a plunker I can help you with debugging.

Comment: yes, I just saw the example and now it is working too.

Comment: glad i was able to help.

Comment: and I think this method will be slower way of sorting as compared to the above. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a simple `sort` function in which you parse the `title` value of each object in the array as an int and compare. Something like this:

```js
var arr = [{
    "title": "1-Introduction"
  },
  {
    "title": "5-Introduction"
  },
  {
    "title": "20-Introduction"
  },
  {
    "title": "4-Introduction"
  }
];


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  const aVal = parseInt(a.title.split("-")[0]);
  const bVal = parseInt(b.title.split("-")[0]);
  return aVal - bVal;
});

console.log(arr);
```